# How do I write 'the little macaron shop' in French? Is it Le petit boutique de macaron?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, commerce

I am asking the above question as I make macarons and when I give them as gifts I want to seal the boxes with stickers saying the above in French.

Comment: There is no such thing as macaron in English. The word is ***macaroon***, a sweet (or pastry) made with almonds.

Comment: I recently learned that "macaron" has become common to distinguish [macaroon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaroon) and [macaron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaron). The Wikipedia page for the latter reads: "In English, most bakers have adopted the French spelling of *macaron* for the meringue-based item, to distinguish the two. This has caused confusion over the correct spelling. Some recipes exclude the use of macaroon to refer to this French confection while others treat the two as synonymous." So *macaroon* might be the original spelling, but it seems like *macaron* has currency too.

Comment: For marketing material such as stickers, watch out for piecewise translations / missing context. If this goes below a brand, for example, I could more easily see it say "<brand name> / Petite boutique de macarons" (without the article)

Answer (score 4):

> La petite boutique de macarons.

In my opinion (native French speaker), using "des" sounds incorrect/ childish

Comment: *Des* is neither incorrect nor (necessarily) childish.

Comment: Native french speaker here. I agree that 'des' sounds incorrect.

Comment: @ApplePie So what about the four real life examples I posted at the end of my reply?

Answer (score 3):

That would be:

> *La petite boutique des macarons.*

Grammatically, *la petite boutique **de** macarons* is "more" correct but less stylish, in my opinion. It would also lead to *la petite boutique de Macron* these days…

Note that *boutique des xxx* is not incorrect. For example "The little shop of horrors" was translated in French by *[La petite boutique des horreurs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Petite_Boutique_des_horreurs_(film,_1986))*.

Also: [*La boutique des saveurs*](http://www.boutiksaveurs.com/), [*La boutique des vins*](http://www.boutiquedesvins-paris.com/), [*La boutique des voyages*](https://www.laboutiquedesvoyages.fr/), [*La boutique des étoffes*](https://www.yelp.fr/biz/la-boutique-des-etoffes-lyon)…

Comment: Merci beaucoup! I really appreciate your knowledge. I'm a beginner with French.

Comment: Ca existe en France les "macarons"?

Comment: @Frank https://www.lebonbon.fr/paris/les-tops-food-et-drink/le-top-des-meilleurs-macarons-de-paris/

Comment: To echo Alone-zee's recent phrase: On peut pas vraiment tourner les talons à Paris sans voir une telle boutique ! Also, to weigh in on the *des* : it sounds a little cutesy to me because it implies that you know these macarons well enough. "Oh, honey, go to that little shop where we get the macarons." Considering that the *la* is performing this same function ("Which little shop?" — "*The* little shop!") *des* isn't out of place, even if it sticks out a little more...

Comment: Ah oui ça existe :-) Je note au passage que je peux maintenant dire: "les tops foods et drink" et espérer être compris sans problème ;-)

Comment: Pourquoi "des" ? Si c'est ce qu'on vend, on utilise "de" (un marchand de tapis, une boutique de vêtements, un stand de légumes). Je vois pas d'option où on dirait "des".

Comment: @TeleportingGoat « La boutique de macarons » est factuel mais peu attractif, on risque de n'y trouver que « du macaron ». « La boutique des macarons » signifie que **les** macarons ont **leur** boutique comme les voisins ont leur maison: « la maison des voisins » et aussi « le musée des voitures anciennes » ou le « jardin des délices »…

Comment: You really see no semantic difference between "the little shop of horrors" and "the little macaron shop"? It was never " the little horror shop". I'm not saying your version is incorrect in French, I'm saying it's not the best translation for the original English sentence given by OP

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I know my suggestion isn't one hundred percent sticking to the English form, but it's on purpose and and I wrote why. You are of course free to disagree. Note also that "the little macaron shop" might also translate to *le magasin du petit macaron* and "the little corner shop" doesn't sell corners ;-)